# Why won't smaller chrono::durations subtract?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use chrono durations as follows but if I increase the ratio to be anything above `std::ratio<1,50>` it throws an error during compilation that `error: no viable overloaded '-='` for when `elapsed -= tickeRate` occurs.

```
int main()
{
    using clock   = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using seconds = std::chrono::seconds;

    std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1,20>> tickRate(1);
//    std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1,60>> tickRate(1);

    clock::time_point start, stop;

    start = clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
    stop  = clock::now();

    clock::duration elapsed = stop - start;

    int i = 0;
    while (elapsed >= tickRate)
    {
        elapsed -= tickRate;
        i++;
    }

    std::cout << "ticked " << i << " times." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first question is, why does it only throw the error when `tickRate` is > 1/50? The second is, what topic can I study so that I can reason through problems like this in the future?

Edit:

Compiler version is: Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)

Additionally this actually works with smaller numbers but not quite sure which.  For me, 1/51 .. 1/99 fail, but 1/100 starts working fine again.  I tried doubles for grins and 1/2500, 1/3600 throw the same error.  Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: On my machine it works perfectly well with `100`, `200` and `1000`. Probably this ratio should be divisible by some number.

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: Seems that way.  I never went past 60 since it failed but after you said this I tried different smaller values.  I'll update the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> template< class Rep2, class Period2 >
> constexpr duration( const duration<Rep2,Period2>& d );
> (4)   (since C++11)
> ```
>
> Constructs a duration by converting d to an appropriate period and
>   tick count, as if by std::chrono::duration_cast(d).count().
>   In order to prevent truncation during conversion, this constructor
>   only participates in overload resolution if no overflow is induced by
>   conversion and:
>
> (1) `std::chrono::treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value == true`
>
> or both:
>
> (2)`std::ratio_divide<Period2, period>::den == 1`,
>       and
>   `std::chrono::treat_as_floating_point<Rep2>::value == false`.  (that is,
>   either the duration uses floating-point ticks, or Period2 is exactly
>   divisible by period)

In this case, the type of `elapsed` is `std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1,20>>`, while that of `tickRate` is  `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration`, which is `std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>` on my amd64 GCC6.1.

When you perform a `-=` operation on `elapsed`, the compiler will try to convert `tickRate` to the same type of `elapsed` itself.

Since `long long` is not an floating point type, clause 2 will be suitable for this case. **This conversion is only valid when `std::high_resolution_clock::period.den` is divisible by your denominator.**

Comment: This makes sense though you reversed the types on `elapsed`/`tickRate`.  The follow up question is -- what is the best way to handle this?  If the duration of  the clock on my compiler/system is not divisible but it is on yours -- how can I know that in advance?  What I did to test is just to `duration_cast<clock::duration>(tickRate)` ahead of time, is there a better way?

Comment: @stewsims:  Here (http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) are some utilities you can use if you would like to truncate in a direction other than towards zero (which is what `duration_cast` does).

Answer (score 6):

To subtract one `duration` from another you should make sure that their periods are aliquots. Here:

```
elapsed -= tickRate;
```

you try to subtract `std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1,60>>` (which is in `1/60` of second intervals) from `clock::duration` which is (at least on MSVC++ 2015) equal to `std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<100,1>,std::nano>>` which happens to be `100 ns`.

Suming up, the problem here is that `1/60 s` is not an integer number of times an interval of `100 ns`.